# Kruskal -Katona theorem and an existence question about the subsets

Tags: combinatorics

Let X be a set with r elements, and let S={A1,A2,...,Am} be a set of subsets of X each having exactly l elements (i.e. |Aj|=l for 1<=j<=m). Further let T be
 the set { B1,B2,...,Bn} of all subsets with l-1 elements  of sets in S
 (i.e. |Bj|= l-1 and each Bj is a subset of some Ak). If l>r/2 it follows easily from Kruskal-katona theorem that the number of elements  of T  is at least |S| or  n>=m. Now my question:
 Can we choose m *distinct* elements of T say C1,C2,...,Cm in a way that every element Aj of S has a subset Cj  for j=1,...,m. In order to avoid double indices I preferred to choose Cj over Bj to denote the elements of T .Of course {C1,C2,...,Cm} is a subset of T. Please note that if we relax the condition of Cj s
being distinct the question becomes trivial.

Comment: A job for Hall's theorem?

Comment: Thank You Lord shark for your comment. representatives in Hall's theorem must be members  of Ajs rather than their subsets. the condition that cjs be subsets opens up more possibilities to find appropriate "representatives". Nevertheless your comment might point towards the right direction.

Comment: It seems that I have an easy solution at last. Define a bipartite graph as follows:  G = ( S, T, E ),AiBj is an edge iff Bj isa subset of Ai. let W be any subset of S and let N G ( W )  denote the neighborhood of W in G i.e. the set of all Bjs in T that are connected to elements of W. Then according to Kruskal-Katona theorem |W| <= | N G ( W )| so that we can apply Hall's theorem to G to get a representer for S.  @ Lord Shark the Unknown may be you are kind enough to take a look at this solution and tell me your take on it.